# Imagebutton.setImageURI(uri) doesn't work

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-studio-2.3

**now my problem is that:**
This is a workaround for Onclcick an ImageButton, which tries to cache the previous image Uri. Passing null effectively resets it.

```
private ImageButton mImageSelect;
private static  final int GALLERY_REQUEST =1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    mImageSelect=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageselect);
    mImageSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode== GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Uri selectedImageUri=data.getData();
        if (null != selectedImageUri) {

            mImageSelect.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"Image Not Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: you cant set  image directly like that

Comment: Mike I wanna ask how to set image in ImageButton from gallery.But setImageUri Not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even if `fileUri` is ready, `setImageUri()` doesn't guarantee to set the image. so its a good practice to always use third party library when dealing with image.
instead of setImageUri(), use Picasso library.

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(fileUri).into(mImageView)
```

Add as dependancy

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/"+R.drawable.image);
mImageSelect.setImageURI(null); 
mImageSelect.setImageURI(imgUri);
```

This is a workaround for refreshing an ImageButton, which tries to cache the previous image Uri. Passing null effectively resets it.

Answer (score 0):

> Imagebutton.setImageURI(uri) doesn't work

You can use Glide to load images more easily

Add this to your build.gradle

```
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide.3.7.0'
```

Load image uri using glide as follows

```
 Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    mImageSelect.setImageURI(Uri.parse(data.getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating Bitmap from uri and setting bitmap on image button.
This can be done as:

```
String path = getPath(this,uri);
```

Code for getPath():

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    Utils.context = context;
    Utils.uri = uri;

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now can get Bitmap as:

```
    if(path!=null)
        Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromPath(path)
```

Set Image on imageButton as:

```
ImageButton.setImageBitmap(bm);
```